# how to create an app-wide object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

My application is a form builder: forms are defined, and activated ones are then presented in the usual CRUD manner. The process of activating a form triggers the `FormManager` to create a subclass of the main Form object (I use STI in `ActiveRecord` to create a subclass of `type`, using `Object.const_set()`). Active forms can be deactivated, which involves killing that subclass definition (using `Object.const_send(:remove...)`)

I require only **1** `FormManager` object for my application. What is the best way to go about this? I am currently using a class variable in `ApplicationController` to achieve this... it works, but seems a bit clunky:

```
require 'lib/form_manager.rb'

class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  helper :all # include all helpers, all the time
  attr_reader :registry

  protect_from_forgery

  @@registry = FormManager.new
end
```

I'm running ruby 1.8.7, rails 2.3.11 in development mode - am I seeing this just because I'm in development mode?

Comment: You might want to make your FormManager a singleton. http://dalibornasevic.com/posts/9-ruby-singleton-pattern-again

Comment: @Pavling: why comment and not the answer? I would give you +1 as it's good idea, but with comment I can't give you points

Comment: meh! I answered another question earlier and got slapped down because I didn't comment... I can't win ;-)

Comment: hehe, well feel free to make an answer and I'll +1 it. The singleton approach is perfect here and works a treat

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, it just works that way. Rails has request-response model, and for every request it creates new instance of some controller (which probably inherits from your ApplicationController), sets some request params and then fires your action method. If you want to share state between requests, you need to put it outside of controller, for example as constant (it's just Ruby) initialized while your application is started by server.

If you need single instance of registry, just put it in "config/initializers/registry.rb":

```
require 'lib/form_manager.rb'

REGISTRY = FormManager.new

Template.all(:conditions => { :is_active => false }).each do |t|
  REGISTRY.loadForm(t.id)
end
```

and then in ApplicationController:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  helper :all # include all helpers, all the time

  protect_from_forgery

  def registry
    REGISTRY
  end
end
```

Comment: Sharing state between requests is a tricky proposition. A global object like this may work while developing, but when the app is deployed it will almost certainly have more than one process running simultaneously. This means more than one FormManager will exist, one in each process. Each FormManager won't be aware of what the others have done, so it is not truly global across the application.

Comment: @Jeff Of course not, thanks for pointing it out. It's global object between requests but within same application. So it shouldn't be used to share state with all application instances. For this the best is some pub/sub mechanism. But it's different story.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to make your FormManager a singleton:

http://dalibornasevic.com/posts/9-ruby-singleton-pattern-again

Answer (score 1):

Yes, a new ApplicationController object will be created for every request (you can check this by adding a before_filter that runs "puts self.id" to check the object id for your controller object. You'll notice it's different for every request).

Why would you want a single object across requests? what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I get the desired effect by making `registry` a class variable, but I feel kinda dirty doing that. about to make an update to answer your second question